# Strava API: download segment efforts fast, possibly with one request

Tags: api, strava

Provided I have a list of Strava activity IDs (around 800), what would be the fastest way to get segment efforts for each of those activities?

Per my understanding of Strava API documentation, currently the only endpoint to include segment efforts is the one that returns an instance of `DetailedActivity`: `/activities/{id}` (https://developers.strava.com/docs/reference/#api-Activities-getActivityById)

But this means I would have to do 800 requests, one for each activity, and this would force the user of my web app to wait.

Yet, there are Strava-powered apps like this one:

https://www.marcellobrivio.com/projects/strava-toolbox/

which, once the user authenticates with Strava, are able to provide analysis of his segment efforts almost instantly.

Could anyone experienced with Strava API advise on how is this achieved?

Comment: I don't know a better approach. If I remember well even apps like VeloViewer ask your authorization to analyze data and gives you result after a certain period of time. After the first call, you could store the returned data to speed up subsequent requests.

Comment: Thanks @tezzo. I managed to reduce the waiting time significantly with asynchronous requests in Python backend. It is much better, but it still bugs me how the author of the app mentioned in my post manages to analyze the segment efforts almost instantly, almost like there was an endpoint to list just the segment efforts data for an athlete.

Comment: I don't know this app and now I can't try it. it gives you instantly results about every segments on your first login (wow!) or only about starred segments (getLoggedInAthleteStarredSegments)? just a note: in Strava API you also have getEffortsBySegmentId to get every attempts of the authenticated user but you always need segmentId.